# Building a string in C

Tags: c, string, idioms, string-building

This seems like a question that would have been asked before, but I couldn't find it. (If you do, please point me there and close this as a duplicate.)

I have C code which works something like this:

```
printf("some characters");
for (; n >= 0; n--)
{
    printf(", %s", f(n, k));
}
printf("more characters");
```

for some variables `n` and `k` and function `char* f(int n, int k)` which are not important here. (`n` and `k` are not constant.) I would like to convert the code above to a function which returns a `char*` rather than simply using `printf` to display it. (It will ultimately be printed but this lets me do some refactoring and is of course easier to test that way.) Of course I could just create the strings and copy them over character-by-character but surely there is a better (cleaner, faster, more idiomatic) way of doing this.

In my particular application `f` is a very simple function, sort of a relative of `itos`, but which is not cacheable in any meaningful way due to `k`. But I welcome ideas which are good for that case as it may be useful to others in the future.

Comment: You can either pass a buffer and length to the function (similar to `snprintf`), or you need to `malloc` a buffer in the function, and then `free` it in the calling code. The third option is to use a `static` or global buffer, but that usually ends badly. Beyond that, there's not much to say, unless you tell us more about the function. And btw, what the heck is `pari_printf`?

Comment: function `char* f(int n, int k)` ...  I would like to convert this to a function which returns a `char*`. I do not get the question. It already returns a `char*`

Comment: @user3386109 The actual function in my code (as opposed to the cleaned-up version above) is converting chunks of a large array into a string. `snprintf` might be an option.

Comment: [man strcat](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcat)

Comment: @Charles, you should post a question about the `const_cast<>` trouble perhaps, using any `*printf %s` over `strcat` to do a string concatenation is kinda ugly (and perhaps a bit inefficient) (imho)

Comment: @Alex `strcat` gets more and more inefficient as the string gets longer, since it must scan the entire string to find the end. And it has no overrun protection.

Comment: @Charles there's no `const_cast<>` or any similar thing in C

Comment: @user3386109 the _dst ptr_ can be incremented (as in your code) and a `strncat` variant exist (to be set with the remaining available buffer size), I'm not going to do it, but I think your answer can be easily modified to use `strncat`. Not here to impose anything, just saying.

Comment: @Alex Yup, but you would have to update the *dst ptr* by calling `strlen`. And if you are updating the *dst ptr* and calling `strlen`, then you may as well just use `memcpy` to move the bytes. I think the real advantage with using `snprintf` would be inside the `f(n,k)` function itself. Since the function will be doing numeric conversions anyways, it may as well use `snprintf` to do the conversions directly into the output string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Step 1 would be to allocate a big enough buffer for the string. Then use `sprintf` to print into the buffer. The standard idiom is

```
int index = sprintf( buffer, "some characters" );
for (; n >= 0; n--)
{
    index += sprintf( &buffer[index], ", %s", f(n, k) );
}
index += sprintf( &buffer[index], "more characters" );
```

The `sprintf` function returns the length of the string that it wrote, which allows you to keep track of where you are in the buffer.

---

You could also have the caller pass a buffer and size. In that case, it's best to use `snprintf` to avoid overrunning the buffer. So the function would look something like this

```
char *create_string( char *buffer, int size, int n, int k )
{
    ...
    index += snprintf( &buffer[index], size-index, ", %s", f(n, k) );
    ...
    return buffer;
}
```

where the `size` parameter is the size of the `buffer`.

Comment: @chux Ok, I changed it from `length` to `size` to avoid confusion, and added some explanatory text. Thanks!

Comment: For your amusement only: here's how this translated into my code: https://github.com/CRGreathouse/PARI-extensions/blob/master/conv.gp.c#L99